# Using cumsum in pandas on group()

Tags: python, group-by, pandas

From a Pandas newbie: I have data that looks essentially like this -

```
 data1=pd.DataFrame({'Dir':['E','E','W','W','E','W','W','E'], 'Bool':['Y','N','Y','N','Y','N','Y','N'], 'Data':[4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]}, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['12/30/2000','12/30/2000','12/30/2000','1/2/2001','1/3/2001','1/3/2001','12/30/2000','12/30/2000']))
data1
Out[1]: 
           Bool  Data Dir
2000-12-30    Y     4   E
2000-12-30    N     5   E
2000-12-30    Y     6   W
2001-01-02    N     7   W
2001-01-03    Y     8   E
2001-01-03    N     9   W
2000-12-30    Y    10   W
2000-12-30    N    11   E
```

And I want to group it by multiple levels, then do a cumsum():

E.g., like `running_sum=data1.groupby(['Bool','Dir']).cumsum()` <-(Doesn't work)

with output that would look something like:

```
Bool Dir Date        running_sum
N    E   2000-12-30           16
     W   2001-01-02            7
         2001-01-03           16
Y    E   2000-12-30            4
         2001-01-03           12
     W   2000-12-30           16
```

My "like" code is clearly not even close. I have made a number of attempts and learned many new things about how not to do this.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
data2 = data1.reset_index()
data3 = data2.set_index(["Bool", "Dir", "index"])   # index is the new column created by reset_index
running_sum = data3.groupby(level=[0,1,2]).sum().groupby(level=[0,1]).cumsum()
```

The reason you cannot simply use `cumsum` on `data3` has to do with how your data is structured.  Grouping by `Bool` and `Dir`  and applying an aggregation function (`sum`, `mean`, etc) would produce a DataFrame of a smaller size than you started with, as whatever function you used would aggregate values based on your group keys.  However `cumsum` is not an aggreagation function.  It wil return a DataFrame that is the same size as the one it's called with.  So unless your input DataFrame is in a format where the output can be the same size after calling `cumsum`, it will throw an error.  That's why I called `sum` first, which returns a DataFrame in the correct input format.

Sorry if I haven't explained this well enough.  Maybe someone else could help me out?

Comment: Thanks for the solution and explanation.  The way I looked at it was to examine the structure of data3.groupby(level=[0,1,2]).sum() which clarified why its necessary to append .groupby(level=[0,1]).cumsum().  I never thought data3.cumsum() would work.

Answer (score 9):

As the other answer points out, you're trying to collapse identical dates into single rows, whereas the cumsum function will return a series of the same length as the original DataFrame. Stated differently, you actually want to group by [Bool, Dir, Date], calculate a sum in each group, THEN return a cumsum on rows grouped by [Bool, Dir]. The other answer is a perfectly valid solution to your specific question, here's a one-liner variation:

```
data1.groupby(['Bool', 'Dir', 'Date']).sum().groupby(level=[0, 1]).cumsum()
```

This returns output exactly in the requested format.

For those looking for a simple cumsum on a Pandas group, you can use:

```
data1.groupby(['Bool', 'Dir']).apply(lambda x: x['Data'].cumsum())
```

The cumulative sum is calculated internal to each group. Here's what the output looks like:

```
Bool  Dir            
N     E    2000-12-30     5
           2000-12-30    16
      W    2001-01-02     7
           2001-01-03    16
Y     E    2000-12-30     4
           2001-01-03    12
      W    2000-12-30     6
           2000-12-30    16
Name: Data, dtype: int64
```

Note the repeated dates, but this is doing a strict cumulative sum internal to the rows of each group identified by the Bool and Dir columns.

Comment: This method gives me a ValueError coming from lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.pyc line 581 which raises it on AttributeError exception. I'm using numpy-1.9.2 and pandas-0.16.2.

Comment: @TrisNefzger: I reproduced your error with the same versions (I was using pandas 14). I've significantly modified my answer to work with newer pandas.