# TypeError: ("sort_values() got multiple values for argument 'axis'", 'occurred at index SUMLEV')

Tags: python, pandas

Why this code

```
cdf = census_df[census_df['SUMLEV'] == 50]
cdf = cdf.apply(lambda x:x.sort_values('CENSUS2010POP', axis=0, ascending=False)).reset_index(drop=True)
cdf = cdf.groupby('STNAME').head(3)
cdf.head(20)
```

gives the following error

```
TypeError: ("sort_values() got multiple values for argument 'axis'", 'occurred at index SUMLEV')
```

While this code works fine

```
cdf = census_df[census_df['SUMLEV'] == 50]
cdf = cdf.groupby('STNAME')
cdf = cdf.apply(lambda x:x.sort_values('CENSUS2010POP', axis=0, ascending=False)).reset_index(drop=True)
cdf = cdf.groupby('STNAME').head(3)
cdf.head(20)
```

But here I needed to do twice groupby, first before sorting and after sorting to pick top 3 values. I wanted first to sort, then group, then pick 3 for every group.

csv file can be found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/words-sdsc/coursera/master/big-data-2/csv/census.csv)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the line:

```
cdf = cdf.apply(lambda x:x.sort_values('CENSUS2010POP', axis=0, ascending=False)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

to:

```
cdf = cdf.sort_values('CENSUS2010POP', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
```

When `.sort_values()` is applied to data frame, it will sort all columns by the column you specified, i.e. `CENSUS2010POP` in this case. You don't have to apply the sort to all columns.

Comment: Actually I am getting error: 
AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'sort_values' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Comment: I think you are using `groupby` before sorting. You can directly apply `sort_values()` to the original data frame without groupby. and group data frame later. Since [pandas group by is stable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39373820/is-pandas-dataframe-groupby-guaranteed-to-be-stable), the data frame will remain sorted after the group by.