# Sorting a column in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Python 3.5, pandas 0.18.1
For sorting the list of population numbers of a state, facing this issue.
Code snippet :filtered_df is existing dataframe with column CENSUS2010POP, 
unique_states is a list

```
for i in unique_states:
    popList = (filtered_df.loc[i, "CENSUS2010POP"]).tolist()
    sorted(popList, reverse=True)
    if(i == "Alabama"):
        print(type(popList))
        print(popList)
```

*sorted* gives error:
**TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable**

**print output :**

*class 'list'

[9045, 10591, 10914, 11299....]*
If it is type list, it should be iterable.
Prob. the actual error is different

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41433632/2901002) can help

Comment: That solution used functions like groupby, which is different from mine

Answer (score 0):

Solved this via :
popList = pd.Series(filtered_df.loc[i,"CENSUS2010POP"] )

But in Python, why do we need to wrap the Series object again by pd.Series?