# Backfill values in Pandas series when value matches another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
import numpy as np

raw_data = {'surface': [np.nan, np.nan, 'round', 'square'],
            'city': ['San Francisco', 'Miami', 'San Francisco', 'Miami']}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['surface', 'city'])
```

This looks like this:

```
        surface city
   0    NaN     San Francisco
   1    NaN     Miami
   2    round   San Francisco
   3    square  Miami
```

I need earliest instance of the San Francisco row to be filled with 'round', and the earlier Miami row to be filled with 'square'. Using .fillna(method='bfill') won't take into account other column values, and just fills all earlier rows with round.

The result would be:

```
        surface city
   0    round   San Francisco
   1    square  Miami
   2    round   San Francisco
   3    square  Miami
```

Comment: Do you want to fill NaN with the first real value from the same city?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby.bfill`; group data frame by *city* column and then use `bfill`:

```
df.groupby('city').bfill()

#  surface           city
#0  round   San Francisco
#1  square          Miami
#2  round   San Francisco
#3  square          Miami
```

Comment: This solution will do a *back fill* on the data frame for each city, if we assume pandas groupby is [stable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39373820/is-pandas-dataframe-groupby-guaranteed-to-be-stable), which probably is.

Answer (score 1):

[Modified based on the admirable answer from [PSidom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43839171/7899410)]

Using `groupby()` is the key point indeed, but it might be confusing not to mention what `bfill()` does as it's not doing what you actually think it does.

Let's take a quick glance at the doc [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#filling-missing-values-fillna).
Instead of back filling the data like what the OP wants, it actually just fill in the missing data with non-missing data in the next column.
It works great with `groupby()` in this case, while you also need to do `groupby('*your group*').ffill()` for forward filling in case that the data you have are more complicated.

For further illustration, let's modify your data like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {'surface': [np.nan, np.nan, 'round', 'square', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
            'city': ['San Francisco', 'Miami', 'San Francisco', 'Miami', 'Miami', 'Miami', 'San Francisco', 'Miami']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['surface', 'city'])
df

#   surface city
#0  NaN     San Francisco
#1  NaN     Miami
#2  round   San Francisco
#3  square  Miami
#4  NaN     Miami
#5  NaN     Miami
#6  NaN     San Francisco
#7  NaN     Miami
```

With only `df.groupby('city').bfill()`, you'll got:

```
df2 = df.groupby('city').bfill()
df2

#   surface city
#0  round   San Francisco
#1  square  Miami
#2  round   San Francisco
#3  square  Miami
#4  NaN     Miami
#5  NaN     Miami
#6  NaN     San Francisco
#7  NaN     Miami
```

See what is going on there? `bfill()` did the job in row 0 and 1, but remain row 4 ~ 7 unchanged. You should use both `bfill()` and `ffill()` instead. Maybe something like this:

```
df3 =  df2.groupby('city').ffill()
df3

#   surface city
#0  round   San Francisco
#1  square  Miami
#2  round   San Francisco
#3  square  Miami
#4  square  Miami
#5  square  Miami
#6  round   San Francisco
#7  square  Miami
```

To be noticed, you shouldn't use something like `df.groupby('city').bfill().ffill()`. It'll fill in something wrong there.