# Cumsum as a new column in an existing Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cumsum

I have a pandas dataframe defined as:

```
A   B   SUM_C      
1   1   10     
1   2   20
```

I would like to do a cumulative sum of SUM_C and add it as a new column to the same dataframe. In other words, my end goal is to have a dataframe that looks like below:

```
A   B   SUM_C   CUMSUM_C       
1   1   10      10     
1   2   20      30
```

---

[Using cumsum in pandas on group()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755057/using-cumsum-in-pandas-on-group) shows the possibility of generating a new dataframe where column name SUM_C is replaced with cumulative sum. However, my ask is to add the cumulative sum as a new column to the existing dataframe.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Just apply `cumsum` on the `pandas.Series` `df['SUM_C']` and assign it to a new column:

```
df['CUMSUM_C'] = df['SUM_C'].cumsum()
```

Result:

```
df
Out[34]: 
   A  B  SUM_C  CUMSUM_C
0  1  1     10       10
1  1  2     20       30
```

Comment: This will fail if you have two columns with the same name. In that case, rename one of them before proceeding.